Forced to Leave Physics PhD Program - How to Salvage Academic Career?
I started my physics PhD program several years ago at a top-ten institute in the U.S. Recently, my supervisor informed me that he believes my talents and interests are not well-aligned with the program. As a result, the department is not allowing me to continue in the PhD program and is asking me to graduate with a master's degree instead. Finding another supervisor within the same department is not an option, as the department has made the decision to discontinue my PhD studies.
Being a scientist and studying the ultimate answers of our universe has been my lifelong goal. I've been working hard and pursuing this goal for so many years, as I set this ambition when I was young. Without a PhD degree, I'll likely be unable to stay in academia as a scientist. (I'm aware of "research scientist" positions in industry that don't necessarily require a PhD, but that's not the path I desire.)
If I decide to reapply for a PhD program elsewhere, I would need reference letters. Given my current supervisor's and department's attitude, I don't think they would write positive recommendations for me, which makes this option challenging. Alternatively, if I enter industry first and then apply for another PhD program later, I doubt my future employer would provide a supportive reference letter, as it would mean I'm planning to leave the job.
I'm reaching out to see if anyone has had a similar experience or can offer advice on how to navigate this situation. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and advice!

Why do they think your talents and interests are not well-aligned with the program?

The most direct reason is that a specific problem continue to exist in my analysis result which does not make any sense to them. They are not able to reproduce the same problem as mine, and I failed to solved it or convince them for several months. Therefore they think my research is not going anywhere and questioned my ability to success in the field.

Is it possible to ask them what evidences can convince them? did they state it clearly? if so, are you able to do that?

Remember that a PhD is just the minimum requirement for the career you describe; getting a PhD does not mean you will have an academic career. I think your chances given your situation are very low, much lower than average, even if you do find a way to complete the PhD.

I’ve literally never heard of a PhD being kicked out that thoroughly. This sounds like you should reevaluate your lifelong goal, not throw the rest of your life at it.

What is your own assessment of the situation? You seem to worry only about the chances of turning this around, but not about whether your skills actually are suitable. People in more favourable situations had less confidence. Do you think this situation is misrepresenting your skills and you are looking for someone who will recommend/supervise/… you truthfully, or do you doubt your skills and are looking for someone who will recommend/supervise/… you regardless?

Expanding a bit on MisterMiyagi's comments, I would not characterize this as "forced to leave physics PhD". Rather, you failed the program. Letting you leave with a masters is meant as a gentler way to fail given the effort already put in, but they're not letting you continue to a PhD because you failed out of the program. From your description in a comment, it sounds like you probably had opportunities previously to avoid failing but stuck to some non-reproducible result.

It is indeed a very unusual situation if your program chooses to let you go rather than finish with a weak degree.  I've never heard of someone being asked to leave because they got stuck on a single issue: were there more issues that you did not mention, such as difficulty with courses, difficulty with presenting a coherent thesis proposal etc?

Welcome to Academia.SE. Your situation is interesting and very much the sort of thing we can help with. But, our format is strictly Q&A: you should post a single question so we can provide the answer. I recommend you [edit] your post to ask a single question. Question #1 is likely not a good fit here ("has anyone ever..." questions are not answerable, except by the trivial, "yes, someone somewhere has doubtless done this before"), but any one of questions #2-4 might be okay. Asking generally for strategies to deal with your situation, while discouraged, is often acceptable as well. Good luck.

Hi @BryanKrause, yes I agree with you that a PhD is just the minimum requirement, and that's why I am so worrying. My supervisor says that it is also probably that other fields in physics suits me, but considering the current situation he doesn't think I should spend more time in my current study so he forced me to graduate with master to save my time.

Hi @MisterMiyagi, according to my supervisor, about 10% of the grad student failed and graduate with a master degree like this, so he told me that it is still kind of normal. Although I am not 100% confident if my skills are suitable, as my supervisor has been discouraging me for some months, I still think that there are some possibility of being misrepresented or just as my supervisor say that it might only not suit this group. He doesn't think that changing to another group is a good idea as I have already spent so many years here and it would be a risk to start another research topic again.

Hi @ZeroTheHero, there are no other issues like difficulty with courses, as I have passed all of them and my supervisor told me that it is one of the reason that they can still give me a master degree as I have completed the course requirements and did have some results on my research.

Hi @cag51, thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my post, and I hope it is better now

How many years is "several years"? Some universities may have (un)official policies regarding how long they will entertain a doctoral candidate. Without significant progress after a substantial amount of time, they may have felt that you were incapable of completing the degree.

Hi @CameronWilliams, it has been four years. However I do not think there is such kind of policy in our university, and it is our supervisor that can decide if we can obtain the degree or not, at least in my case.

@pcc I think unfortunately phrases like other fields in physics would suit you are probably just kind words, plus a humble recognition by your supervisor that they cannot speak for all of physics.

@BryanKrause Yeah I agree this is a possible explanation, because if I am in his position I would probably say the same words. Only my supervisor himself would know what he actually thinks, so I don't think I can make a decision merely based on that.

@pcc did you just pass your courses, or did you pass with flying colours? Do you (honestly) view your PhD as closer to a hobby or to a job?

@NAMcMahon I passed the required courses with 3 A's and 1 B. For me I view my PhD as a job as well as a hobby.


I started my physics PhD program several years ago at a top-ten institute in the U.S. Recently, my supervisor informed me that he believes my talents and interests are not well-aligned with the program. As a result, the department is not allowing me to continue in the PhD program and is asking me to graduate with a master's degree instead.

The bad news is that you are being forced out. The good news is that you are earning a master's degree, so you have something to show for your efforts so far.

Finding another supervisor within the same department is not an option, as the department has made the decision to discontinue my PhD studies.

I rather doubt this is true. My guess is that the department does not want to fund you while you look for another advisor, nor do they want to force your current advisor to continue supporting you. They are probably also concerned that you would graduate way behind schedule if you switched advisors. So it's understandable that they are not really giving you an option to look for another advisor. But even so, my guess is that if you showed up within a week with an advisor who wanted to hire you, they would certainly allow this. Of course, finding an advisor on such a short timeline and under such circumstances may be impossible.

The most direct reason is that a specific problem continue to exist in my analysis result which does not make any sense to them. They are not able to reproduce the same problem as mine, and I failed to solved it or convince them for several months. Therefore they think my research is not going anywhere and questioned my ability to success in the field.

It's very hard to judge this from the outside. The problem here could be any combination of (a) your advisor being a jerk, or (b) this particular environment being the wrong match for you, or (c) you having behavioral issues or other limitations that will limit you no matter what you do. It's also very hard to judge yourself. So be kind to yourself. This will be a very uncertain and stressful time, and it may be a long road before you figure out where you are supposed to be. But have confidence that you are not going to spend the rest of your life in misery; you'll eventually figure it out.

Being a scientist and studying the ultimate answers of our universe has been my lifelong goal. I've been working hard and pursuing this goal for so many years, as I set this ambition when I was young. Without a PhD degree, I'll likely be unable to stay in academia as a scientist.

I'm sure you know that most PhDs feel this way, but a very small fraction of PhDs become professors. Even without this hiccup, the odds were always very much against you. In the long run, you may be very happy that you were forced off the tenure track now, rather than a decade from now.

I'm aware of "research scientist" positions in industry that don't necessarily require a PhD, but that's not the path I desire.

Do you know anything about these positions, or are you just assuming? There is a lot of propaganda about how universities solve the big mysteries while industry jobs are all about getting more clicks or selling more widgets. This is certainly partially true; there are plenty of horrible industry jobs that I would never want to do. But if you look a little deeper, you will find permanent, well-paying positions that really are R&D. On the other hand, the best positions are competitive, and your lack of a PhD may be a problem.

If I decide to reapply for a PhD program elsewhere, I would need reference letters. Given my current supervisor's and department's attitude, I don't think they would write positive recommendations for me, which makes this option challenging.

Probably true, but hopefully at least one professor likes you. You can always go back to your undergraduate professors to get the other two, but it would certainly be nice to have at least one letter from your current institution that can corroborate your version of events, even if it is somewhat mixed. Indeed, it would be strange to have a glowing letter under the circumstances, so a letter that is mixed but fair is probably okay. Of course, you will not get into another top-10 program, but I strongly suspect you'll be able to earn a PhD somewhere.

Alternatively, if I enter industry first and then apply for another PhD program later, I doubt my future employer would provide a supportive reference letter, as it would mean I'm planning to leave the job.

I do not think this is likely. While you might not want to tell your actual boss that you're thinking of leaving, most companies have plenty of principal or chief scientists who can (and do) write letters under these circumstances. The bigger problem is that as time passes, you will want to buy a house, start a family, start building wealth, etc., so very few people return to the PhD stipend after they leave.

I'm reaching out to see if...can offer advice on how to navigate this situation.


Calm down. Depending on your timeline, maybe take a few days to digest your situation. You have some tricky conversations coming up, so if you're panicking, wait a few days before launching into them if possible.
Look around for other professors in your current department who might adopt you. Preferably ones for whom you have skills / past work that is relevant, so you are not starting from zero. This is unlikely to work, but I would spend a few days trying very hard.
Talk to your advisor or others in your circle about transferring to a lower-ranked grad school and getting a letter of recommendation. Better to know now if they're willing to write and how negative it would be. If you have collaborators at another such school, you might talk to them directly.
Spend a few days deep-diving into industry jobs. You will find many that seem horrible, but keep going, there are some interesting things there. Start applying now. (As I write this, Aug 2024, my LinkedIn feed suggests that the job market for tech in the US is pretty bad...so even if this is your "backup plan," don't wait too long to start looking).
Plan to re-apply to graduate school in the next cycle.


As one data point, I have written multiple letters of recommendation for lab technologists who want to go to grad school for a PhD. All have been successful applicants. Most of them were open during the job interview of that being their plan and I was happy to have them work a few years.

Yes, I changed universities after it became impossible to advance. I actually wound up at a higher rated university and with a much more capable advisor (world class, actually). My reasons were different, but among them was an unhelpful advisor.
I was highly recommended by another faculty member at the time, though he was in a different sub-field. But he was sure that I had the ability to succeed and made the switch possible.
You may have the opportunity to find such a person also, especially in the US where you have taken courses with other professors and, perhaps, interacted with them in other ways, such as being a TA. You may have a general reputation at the current place as an able person. If so, you can try to find a way to capitalize on that in a future application process.
And, it is even possible that your advisor's opinion is narrowly focused on the project at hand, and not on you as a future academic generally. Think about whether that is true or not and consider having a frank discussion with them.
Note also that my earlier failure to advance had no effect on my career. The degree and the quality of the dissertation was the important thing.

Hi @Buffy, thanks for sharing your experience. I am going to be a TA next semester, so I will also try to take that chance. I had some discussions with my supervisor but he did not comment too much on my prospective future in academic generally, only telling me that switching to other sub-field in the future is also a possibility, but that would take me a lot of risks so he does not recommend me to do so now.
